# Simplest way to build dotnet SDK project requiring net461 on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, .net-core, rider, dotnet-sdk

I have a dotnet SDK `.sln` (and a `build.proj`) with `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>`. It builds on Windows using Visual Studio and `dotnet build`, but I'd also like it to build as many other places as possible. What do I need to put in my README.md and/or what can I put in the project files to make it build on Rider and/or on from bash on a Mac?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(using *.NET **Core** SDK*) The simplest way to build for a *.NET Framework* [TFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-framework-versions) when running on either **macOS** or **Linux** using the [.NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/), is to utilize the [.NET Framework Targeting Pack Nuget Packages](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/reference-assemblies) from *Microsoft* (<strike>currently in preview</strike>):

> These packages enable building .NET Framework projects on any machine with at least MSBuild or the .NET Core SDK installed.
>
> The following scenarios and benefits are enabled for .NET Framework projects:
>
> - Build without requiring admin operations to install pre-requisites such as Visual Studio or .NET Framework targeting packs.
> - Build libraries on any operating system supported by the .NET Core SDK.
> - Build Mono-based projects.

You may either include the [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies/) metapackage;
or use just the specific package, which is in your case [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net461](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net461/).

Add the package to the `*.csproj` or your `Directory.Build.props`:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note: The `PrivateAssets` attribute controls which dependency assets will be consumed but won't flow to the parent project. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

#### Update

This is no longer required using the *.NET 5 SDK* (e.g. *5.0.100*), which will now automatically add the `PackageReference` to the *ReferenceAssemblies* for *.NET Framework*.

Comment: Works fantastically, thanks! Even more, thanks for taking the time to do such a detailed answer with all the trimmings - here's hoping it garners the upvotes it deserves!

Answer (score 3):

In order to build via bash on a vanilla Mac, the minimal steps seem to be:

- Install Mono 6.0 (5.2 is recommended for VS Mac interop, I dont care about that, and Mono 6.0's interop with Dotnet core is better)
- Install dotnet SDK 2.2 (doesn't have to be exactly that, but it works for me)
- Put this in a Directory.build.props file (open to improvements if anyone has any)

> ```
> <Project>
>      <PropertyGroup>
>        <IsOSX Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))'== 'true'">true</IsOSX>
>      </PropertyGroup>
>      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(IsOSX)' == 'true' ">
>         <FrameworkPathOverride>/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/../lib/mono/4.6.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
>      </PropertyGroup>
> </Project>
> ```

- Bash: `dotnet build SolutionFileName.sln` should now work
- Install Rider 2019.1 or later
- Rider: should Just Work (it should autodetect msbuild 16.0 in the build tools section)